# How to save Python in-memory dictionary to a file as a Python source code?

Tags: python, serialization, configuration, dictionary, code-generation

How to get Python **source code** representation of in-memory Python dictionary?

I decided to ask this question after reading Thomas Kluyver's [comment](http://www.robg3d.com/?p=1000#comment-31367) on Rob Galanakis' blog post titled [Why bother with python and config files?](http://www.robg3d.com/?p=1000) In his comment Thomas states

> But if you want any way to change settings inside the application
>   (like a preferences dialog), there’s no good way to automatically
>   write a correct Python file.

Comment: You mean make a `.py` file with the text `a_dict = {'key1' : 'value1'}` inside it, or something that is lower level?

Comment: I think Kluyver just meant there's nothing built-in to Python to do it, not that it can't be done (nor that it is difficult).

Comment: @martineau How about Ignacio's answer?

Comment: @Piotr Dobrogost: I guess I was wrong and there _is_ something built-in at least for basic types -- in which case I'm not sure what Kluyver meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming it uses only "basic" Python types, you can write out the `repr()` of the structure, and then use `ast.literal_eval()` to read it back in after.

Comment: There's no guarantee `repr` will produce correct Python source code, right?

Comment: No. It will if there are only basic types- strings, dictionaries, lists, ints, etc- but not if, for example, you define a class of your own and try to save an instance of it.

Comment: It will if the contents consist solely of basic types.

Comment: Could you point the place in the docs stating that `repr()` is guaranteed to produce correct Python source code for basic Python types? I have no idea why `repr()` link in the table at http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html links to _8.19. repr — Alternate repr() implementation_ instead of the documentation of the built-in `repr()`...

Comment: [It's buried](http://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#PyTypeObject.tp_repr): "Ideally, this function should return a string that, when passed to `eval()`, given a suitable environment, returns an object with the same value."

Comment: Thanks. I remember reading this statement in the past and that's why I asked if there's any guarantee as this doesn't sound like one...

Comment: If you're willing to use `eval()` instead of `ast.literal_eval` (and yes, I am aware of the issues) you can easily extend it to handle your own classes.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Actually the correct link to built-in `repr()` function's documentation is http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr. See http://bugs.python.org/issue14489

Answer (score 1):

As the article says, you're better off using JSON/YAML or other formats, but if you seriously wanted to use a Python dict and are only using basic Python types...

**Writing out (attempt to use pformat to try and make it more human readable):**

```
from pprint import pformat # instead of using repr()

d = dict(enumerate('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))
open('somefile.py').write(pformat(d))
```

**Reading back**:

```
from ast import literal_eval
d = literal_eval(open('somefile.py').read())
```

Comment: _As the article says, you're better off using JSON/YAML or other formats_ Not really, the article says exactly the opposite :)